# Antora playbook execution crashes when having multiple source repositories

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, antora

I use Antora 2.3 since sometime now and I had to introduce more source repositories into my playbook.yaml file as the documentation-site grew.

Currently, I have 50-60 Git repos, each of size around 15 MB, mentioned in the playbook.
Afterwards, my site generation began to crash while parallelly cloning the repositories mentioned in my `content.sources[]` of playbook.yaml (i.e. exits from the Antora command in Linux shell without any errors).

I tried allocating more memory and received same above issue

```
node --max-old-space-size=16384 `which antora` --cache-dir=./.cache/antora --generator custom-generate-site playbook.yaml --stacktrace
```

Comment: Do you have 16gigs of memory to allocate to Antora? You didn't provide any system specs. If memory availability is not a problem, this sounds like an issue that should be reported here: https://gitlab.com/antora/antora/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes, I also believe 16gigs would be quite enough for us to conclude there is a problem.

Comment: Some versions of Node.js have exhibited larger than expected memory use, particularly in the 14.x range. If it's possible, try upgrading to a 16.x version to see if memory use is lower.